Solution of a transcendental equation
Let $a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4,a_5 \in \mathbb{R}$, $a_1 \neq 0$ and consider the transcendental equation
$$
(1) \quad a_1x^2 + a_2x + a_3 + a_4 e^{-2a_5x} + a_6 xe^{-a_5x} +  a_7e^{-a_5x} = 0.
$$
Is there a way to solve explicitly this equation? I know how to deal with it in the particular case with $a_1 = 1$ and $a_2 = a_3 = a_7 = 0$, that is,
$$
x^2 + a_4 e^{-2a_5x} + a_6 xe^{-a_5x} = 0.
$$
In this case, we multiply last equation by $e^{2a_5x}$ in order to obtain
$$
e^{2a_5 x}x^2 + a_6xe^{a_5x} + a_4 = 0,
$$
that is
$$
(xe^{a_5x})^2 + a_6xe^{a_5x} + a_4 = 0
$$
and denoting $y = xe^{a_5 x}$ the equation becomes
$$
y^2 + a_6y + a_4 = 0,
$$
which has a solution and I know what to do. Is there a way to use this same idea to solve (1)?
Edit: Without loss of generality we can assume $a_1 = 1$.

I agree with you, I will edit it.

Wlog, $a_1=1$. You can then generalize your method if $a_3=a_2^2/4$ and $a_7=a_6a_2/2$. The equation still becomes $y^2+a_6y+a_4=0$, where now $y=e^{a_5x}(x+a_2/2)$.

It is very unlikely that your equation can be solved in closed form in its full generality.  You can get series solutions, e.g. in powers of $a_5$.

Given $y$, is there a way to find $x$ such that $y = e^{a_5 x}(x+a_2/2)$?

Yes, $$x = \dfrac{ 2 W\left(a_5 y \exp(a_2 a_5/2)\right)-a_2 a_5}{2 a_5}$$
where $W$ is a branch of the Lambert W function.

The accepted answer gives cases of the equation which are easier to solve. Is a more general solution wanted?

@TymaGaidash Yes, I'm interested in a more general closed-form solution.

Your method of resolution can be "reverse-engineered" as it follows. Substitute the variable $y = \alpha e^{-\lambda x} + \beta x + \gamma$ inside the quadratic equation $ay^2 + by + c = 0$ and compare the coefficients with your own parametrization, hence
$$
\begin{cases}
   a_1 = a\beta^2 \\
   a_2 = \beta(2a\gamma + b) \\
   a_3 = a\gamma^2 + b\gamma + c
\end{cases}
\quad\&\quad
\begin{cases}
   a_4 = a\alpha^2 \\
   a_6 = 2a\alpha\beta \\
   a_7 = \alpha(2a\gamma + b)
\end{cases},
$$
letting aside the obviously renamed parameter $a_5 = \lambda$. In consequence, one understands that your method will be able to a solution to the original problem if and only if the above system of equations can be solved for $(a,b,c)$ and $(\alpha,\beta,\gamma)$ in terms of $a_{1,2,3,4,6,7,}$.
Unfortunately, not all cases can recasted as such, meaning that the present method fails to cope with every instances of the problem. Indeed, the reparametrization implies the subcondition $a^6 = (2\alpha\beta)^2 = 4a_1a_2$ for example, which is not fulfilled in general.

Addendum.
In the cases where your change of variable works, then one needs to solve the following equation :
$$
\alpha e^{-\lambda x} + \beta x + \gamma = y_\pm, \;\;\text{with}\;\; y_\pm = \frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}.
$$
Its solutions are given by
$$
x_k^\pm = \frac{1}{\lambda}W_k\left(-\frac{\lambda\alpha}{\beta}e^{\lambda(\gamma-y_\pm)/\beta}\right) - \frac{\gamma-y_\pm}{\beta}
$$
where $W_k$ is the $k^\mathrm{th}$ branch of the Lambert function.

Thank you! If I understood it correctly, $\alpha$ is a constant. But, in my first attempt with $a_1 = 1$, and $a_2 = a_3 = a_7 = 0,$ the substitution was $y = xe^{a_5x}$. Do you mean, I could have made a change of variables like $y = \alpha e^{-\lambda x} + \beta x + \gamma $ even in this more simples case ?

@LucasLinhares. Actually, you factored the exponential $e^{-a_5x}$ before working with the quadratic equation, while I started directly from the original equation. Then you can apply my procedure to the quantity $\tilde{y} = ye^{\lambda x}$ instead, or alternatively you might consider non-constant coefficients in order to compensate the exponential prefactor, such as $\tilde{b} = be^{\lambda x}$ and $\tilde{c} = ce^{\lambda x}$ (hence $\tilde{y}\pm = y\pm e^{\lambda x}$). In the end, this is only a matter of reparametrization.

@LucasLinhares. And other substutions than the one discussed here remain possible obviously and can lead to completely new solutions.

1.)
$$a_1x^2+a_2x+a_3+a_4e^{-2a_5x}+a_6xe^{-a_5x}+a_7e^{-a_5x}=0$$
$$(a_1x^2+a_2x+a_3)+a_4e^{-2a_5x}+(a_6xe+a_7)e^{-a_5x}=0$$
You can solve the equation in terms of elementary functions if you set some of the $a_1,...,a_7$ to zero so that the equation contains either $x$ or $e^x$.
If the equation can be transformed to a polynomial equation with nonzero degree of both $x$ and $e^x$ simultaneously without a univariate factor, we don't know how to solve for $x$ by rearranging the equation by applying only finite numbers of only elementary functions.
If $a_1,...,a_7$ all are algebraic numbers and the equation can be transformed to a polynomial equation with nonzero degree of both $x$ and $e^x$ simultaneously without a univariate factor, the equation cannot have solutions that are elementary numbers except $0$.
Let $c$ be a constant. The equation is solvable in terms of elementary functions together with the nonelementary special function Lambert W

if there is only one exponential monomial and one $x$-power monomial,
if there is only one $e^{cx}$ and one summand linear in $x$,
if there are only two exponential summands, or
if there are only one or two exponential summands with factors linear in $x$.

Also, the equation can be simplified to some of these cases if all summands have a power of $x$ as factor.
2.)
Following your way:
$$a_1x^2+a_2x+a_3+a_4e^{-2a_5x}+a_6xe^{-a_5x}+a_7e^{-a_5x}=0$$
$$a_1x^2(e^{a_5x})^2+a_2x(e^{a_5x})^2+a_3(e^{a_5x})^2+a_4+a_6xe^{a_5x}+a_7e^{a_5x}=0$$
$$e^{a_5x}=\frac{1}{2}\frac{(-a_6x-a_7+\sqrt{a_6^2x^2+2a_6xa_7+a_7^2-4a_4a_1x^2-4a_4a_2x-4a_4a_3}}{a_1x^2+a_2x+a_3},-\frac{1}{2}\frac{a_6x+a_7+\sqrt{a_6^2x^2+2a_6xa_7+a_7^2-4a_4a_1x^2-4a_4a_2x-4a_4a_3}}{a_1x^2+a_2x+a_3}$$
This equation is solvable by Lambert W if the right-hand side of the equation is a linear term of $x$ or are a constant multiplied by $x^2$.
This equation is solvable by the Generalized Lambert W of Mező et. al. if the right-hand side of the equation is a rational expression of $x$.
We can build the corresponding equation systems and solve for $a_1,...,a_7$.

COMMENT.-With a plotter it is very easy. Without a plotter it is very difficult.
Example: We have $$e^{a_5x}=\frac{-(a_6x+a_8)}{a_1x^2+a_2x+a_3}\space \text {where } a_8=a_4+a_7$$


OP seems to be looking for an explicit solution. Could you add this as a comment instead of an answer?

This is not an answer but a comment. I put it here because of the figure giving an explicit example. Give some values to the coefficients in order  to can  solve the problem is to elude it in its generality which is not possible by elementary means (as occurs with trascendental equation).

I endorse this practice ... Label it "COMMENT" and put it in the answer space when (for example) a graphic could not be shown in an actual comment.
